# Using Mavlink2rest server to send telemetry data to my program and also be able to send mavlink commands to the drone with Auterion

Tags: mavlink

I'm using a mavlink2rest server to send commands to my drone simulation and also receive the telemetry data. I was using mission planner and I had no problems there but now I need to switch over to Auterion. Does anyone have any idea as how to connect my Auterion simulation to my mavlink2rest server.

I haven't tried much yet due to the limited amount of simulation time that Auterion gives me.